# Replace app.config file while app is in use

Tags: c#, app-config

We need to make a small change to a string in our application's app.config file.

To avoid a full packaged roll out to all PCs we want to replace the app.config file on each one.

Will the application lock the app.config file if it is currently using it all will it allow it to be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.config is cached on first access, so the file is not locked for the entire duration of the program execution.

That said, any changes you make will not have affect until the program is next restarted.

Answer (score 0):

It should be replaceable just fine (all else being equal), but the loaded data won't be invalidated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` namespace. Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Things to consider:

- Does the **user** have write permissions for App.Config?
- Do you need the changes to be implemented straight away?

For the latter, ensure that you call the `RefreshSection(...)` routine before terminating the application. Otherwise, your application will most likely revert to its cached copy of **app.config**.